# Invalid response object from API: (HTTP response code was 0)

Tags: ubercart

I am using Ubercart and stripe and enabled  [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_stripe) its working great for my dev version which is `HTTP` but when I use similar at live site having `HTTPS` I get below error.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong or what i need to resolve it, I tried searching it tried support but not able to find any solution.

Please suggest!

> Payment failed for order 32: Stripe Customer Creation Failed for order
>   32: Invalid response object from API: (HTTP response code was 0)

Thanks!

Comment: The stripe API returned a 0 when the module was expecting a 200 - you'd need to inspect your server's ability to make outgoing requests to Stripe's domain(s), the payload being sent to Stripe, Stripe's docs, and/or consult Stripe's maintenance/alert channels to work out where the problem is

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will keep continue to check further. I there anything we need to check with library or manually changing anything in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the stripe api and ran all it's unit tests. That way I could find that curl was disabled. By enabling following functions in php, all unit tests succeeded and it got working:

```
shell_exec
proc_open
curl_exec
```